# Using conditional operator without assigning its outcome

Tags: java, conditional-operator

Why do I have to assign the result of the following conditional expression to a variable to get it to compile?

```
piece.isWhite() ? whitePieceSquares.add(getSquare(pos)) : blackPieceSquares.add(getSquare(pos));
```

The above doesn't compile, the below does:

```
boolean garbage = piece.isWhite() ? whitePieceSquares.add(getSquare(pos)) : blackPieceSquares.add(getSquare(pos));
```

`List#add()` returns a boolean, but I would just ignore that. Is it just that the conditional operator is designed in such a way that it's necessary to assign values returned from functions and those returning functions must have the same type?

Comment: By "it doesn't parse", do you mean "it doesn't compile"? Also, what is the return type of `isWhite()`?

Comment: Okay, fine. It can't compile because it doesn't parse correctly. I'm glad we fixed that. It would have confused anyone trying to read it.

Comment: And isWhite is a boolean (obviously because it compiles). Way to edit your comment to pretend you were making a helpful comment.

Comment: "Way to edit your comment to pretend you were making a helpful comment." -- that'll motivate others to help.

Comment: @schnozzinkobenstein: Sarcasm will get you nowhere. You asked *us* for help. I was trying to make the question more clear for anyone else trying to help *you*. Also, the second version will compile if `isWhite()` returns an integer (1 or 0).

Comment: @Evan: *"Also, the second version will compile if isWhite() returns an integer (1 or 0)."* Uhm, this question is tagged Java, not PHP or JS or whatever weak typed language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [section 14.8 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.8) (expression statements):

> Certain kinds of expressions may be used as statements by following them with semicolons:
>
> ```
> ExpressionStatement:
>       StatementExpression ;
>
> StatementExpression:
>        Assignment
>        PreIncrementExpression
>        PreDecrementExpression
>        PostIncrementExpression
>        PostDecrementExpression
>        MethodInvocation
>        ClassInstanceCreationExpression
> ```
>
> An expression statement is executed by evaluating the expression; if the expression has a value, the value is discarded. Execution of the expression statement completes normally if and only if evaluation of the expression completes normally.
>
> Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language allows only certain forms of expressions to be used as expression statements.
>
> ...
>
> On the other hand, the language allows all the most useful kinds of expressions in expressions statements, and it does not require a method invocation used as an expression statement to invoke a void method, so such a trick is almost never needed. If a trick is needed, either an assignment statement (§15.26) or a local variable declaration statement (§14.4) can be used instead.

Basically, the *principle aim* of a conditional operator is to evaluate its operands - you're using it for the side-effects.

Peter Lawrey's answer shows a better use - you use the conditional operator to work out which square to add the piece to, and then you invoke the method on that.

Comment: So is Peter Lawrey's version of my code a correct use, or if I used that am I still just using it for the side-effects?

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand it still. Should I only be using it if I need it to: someVariable=conditional-operator?

Comment: @schnozzinkobenstein: Peter's answer is a perfectly reasonable use for it - the conditional expression itself probably doesn't *have* side effects, but you're using the *result* of it as the target of the side-effecting method. Personally I'd probably use a local variable rather than invoking the method directly on the result of the expression, but they're logically the same.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
(piece.isWhite() ? whitePieceSquares : blackPieceSquares).add(getSquare(pos));
```

EDIT: Not sure why there is doubt this is a valid statement. Here is a shorter example which you should be able to compile/run.

```
boolean out = true;
(out ? System.out : System.err).println("Hello");
```

Comment: Also not a statement. And neithe is 1+1; I think John Skeet pikked up the relevant part of the spec; the special class of ExpressionStatements which don't have to assign their values to a variable.

Comment: What makes you think its not a statement?

Comment: No, this works perfectly fine, because the outermost term in the expression is a method invocation, therefore it can be a statement. But a ?: on its own cannot.

Comment: I think this is valid because you actually use the return value of the ?: expression.

Answer (score 2):

In C, that would be possible, because you can write something like

```
void foo(int bar) {
    bar;
}
```

In java, you can't, and I don't miss it. However, if you for some reason don't like writing if ... else ..., this should compile:

```
(piece.isWhite() ? whitePieceSquares : blackPieceSquares).add(getSquare(pos));
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, but why? Tested both Java and C, and both compile.

Comment: @extraneon - it is legal and should compile perfectly in Java

Comment: You're right. You're using the return value which makes it a valid expression. I'll update the vote as soon as I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the answer is: just because. `?:` and all the arithmetic operators can only appear on the right-hand side of an expression.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your `add` functions return a boolean. Those have to go somwhere, don't they?

Comment: No, you can throw away the return value of any expression.

Comment: My post says that the add functions return a boolean, so you don't have to guess.

Comment: it still didn't compile if `add` is defined to return `void`.